# La contraseña me aparece encriptada y a pesar que voy a la consola y le agrego esto me sigue apareciendo como encriptada a que se debe esto?

Tags: php, html, ajax, phpmyadmin, web

Ayudenme porfavor ocupo este trabajo.

[image: El codigo encriptado]

[image: El comando para tratar de desencriptarlo]

Comment: Saludos. Lo que pides es imposible con la información que pones. Puede ser desde un Base64, un Hash o alguno de las funciones de cifrado que dispone (en tu caso) MySQL; Debes checar los elemento necesarios según el caso que requieres para ello (en el caso de Hash no son reversibles; es decir caso perdido).

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: El dato de la clave está en una caja (la columna). Estás cambiando el tamaño o forma de la caja; el contenido es el mismo. Nada de lo que muestras cambia cómo se almacena la clave. De paso, por favor revisa cómo se publican preguntas acá, como te indican en los otros comentarios.

Answer (score -1):

En MySQL la encriptación de PASSWORD() es **unidireccional**, es decir NO es posible "desencriptarla", y tampoco se puede usar campos cortos para el almacenaje del resultado, precisamente por la longitud de clave que usa MySQL al generarla.
Lo que puedes hacer, como te comentaron, es usar otro método de encriptación (AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRIPT, ver https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html) o de ofuscamiento (Base64) para esconder la clave.

Comment: Tengo que dejar un -1, porque hay varias cosas que podrían expresarse mejor. Primero Password() no provee encriptación. De hecho, la encriptación siempre funciona en dos vías. [`Password`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html) utiliza un algoritmo para producir un  _hash_ de la contraseña, pero [sacar un hash no es encriptar](https://nordlocker.com/blog/hashing-vs-encryption/). Luego, Base64 no es un algoritmo de ofuscamiento. Base64 es un algoritmo de codificación, y codificar no es lo mismo que ofuscar.

Comment: Bueno, todo eso yo lo sé. He trabajado con MySQL desde 2005, por lo cual tengo claro qué hace MySQL, las palabras que usé eran para una rápida comprensión del problema coloquialmente. Ten en cuenta que es usual entre quienes se iniican suponer que PASSWORD() encripta, aunque en realidad no lo hace, pero no es la primera vez que veo a alguien queriendo "desencriptar", lo que no es posible y el mismo manual lo dice. Por su lado también se que Base64 no es ofuscación ni encriptación, aunque ciertos métodos de autenticación usan eso. Es un tema coloquial. Por eso le propuse usar AES_ENCRYPT.

Comment: Considero que, en una respuesta de Stack Overflow, habría que usar la terminología correcta. Entiendo que hay que bajar lo posible el nivel para que un principiante pueda introducirse al tema, pero considero que es particularmente importante en ese caso usar la terminología correcta para evitar que caiga en mayor confusión. Si decides cambiar la redacción de tu respuesta, con gusto te daría un voto positivo. Un saludo.